# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jnidispatch (/com/sun /jna/win32-x86/jnidispatch.dll) not found in resource path

Tags: java, jar, jna

I have a small test program which runs perfectly in the JBuilder 6 debugger. When I make a .jar file and run it I get an error

```
>java -jar testadll.jar
Start of DLL test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jnidispatch (/com/sun
/jna/win32-x86/jnidispatch.dll) not found in resource path
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeLibraryFromJar(Native.java:708)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:685)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:109)
    at testadll.TestThisDLL$PenniesLib.<clinit>(TestThisDLL.java:24)
    at testadll.TestThisDLL.main(TestThisDLL.java:33)
```

I have searched my drive and there is no jnidispatch.dll on it.

The program is

```
package testadll;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
//import com.sun.jna.NativeLong;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
//import com.sun.jna.*;



public class TestThisDLL {
   public interface PenniesLib extends StdCallLibrary {
    PenniesLib INSTANCE = (PenniesLib) Native.loadLibrary(
            "PenniesLib", PenniesLib.class);
        int a();
    }

  public static void main( String args[] ) {
      System.out.println("Start of DLL test");
      //TestDLL t = new TestDLL();
      //System.out.println("DLL loaded");
      int value = PenniesLib.INSTANCE.a();
      System.out.println("DLL response is " + String.valueOf(value));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you included the file `jna.jar` in your classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've apparently merged JNA's classes with your own jar file, but omitted its native support.  Ensure that *all* files from the original `jna.jar` (not just class files) are copied to the new destination and that their original paths are preserved.

Specifically, your jar file *must* include com/sun/jna/win32-x86/jnidispatch.dll.  If you want to include support for other platforms, you must include com/sun/jna/*/*jnidispatch* as well.

Comment: I couldn't find a way of getting JBuilder 6 to do it. I got it to work by using WinZip and extracting the contents of jna.jar to the same directory as TestaDLL.jar. I then updated TestaDll.jar by running jar -uf0 testadll.jar com\sun\jna\win32-x86\jnidispatch.dll. Is this the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: Ask in a JBuilder support forum.  Most IDEs will let you customize what goes into a jar file.

Comment: Read the section [Images and Other Resources](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26914) on how to include non-class files in a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a version of jna.jar, that supports 64 bit, for example
jna-4.1.0.jar or jna-3.4.0.jar.