# Couldn't load library from loader

Tags: java, android, dll, jna

I have a problem loading some .dll libraries through my android app, in fact there is tons of questions about this issue but not any one of them solves my problem, the following is how I'm trying to implement them:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    System.loadLibrary("NetSDKDLL"); // this is where I'm getting the Exception
    simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary(
            ("NetSDKDLL"), simpleDLL.class);
  }

   public interface NetSDKDLL extends StdCallLibrary {
      int IP_NET_DVR_RealPlay(NativeLong nLoginId);
   }
}
```

And this is the log:

```
01-29 12:20:34.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 12:20:34.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): Process: com.example.removed, PID: 1623
01-29 12:20:34.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load NetSDKDLL from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.removed-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.removed-2, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
01-29 12:20:34.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
01-29 12:20:34.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
01-29 12:20:34.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at com.example.removed.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
```

And to give a clear overview:

1- I've no problem in SDK and it's path is already assigned in eclipse and in System Environments.

2- the dll libraries are placed in a source folder called **dll**.

3- the dll libraries also placed in **libs** folder.

4- I'm using the same way in a regular Java app and it works perfectly.

---

Updates:

new Exception:

```
02-01 09:18:44.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/android-i686/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.)
```

Comment: Probably not your only issue, but you shouldn't be using `StdCallLibrary` for android.  `stdcall` is pretty much specific to windows.

Comment: You also don't need to call `System.loadLibrary()`.  Let JNA do the loading in `Native.loadLibrary()`.  You only need to call `System.loadLibrary()` when loading dependent libraries or when loading your own JNI bindings.

Comment: @technomage well, I took care of your notes and the problem behavior is changed now and there is a new Exception type which is described in the above updates, kindly have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You're missing JNA's own native support.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346438/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-jnidispatch-com-sun/17346812#17346812).

Note that you'll need to follow Android's specific rules for bundling and loading native code with your app.

**EDIT**

Specifically, your project must include the resource path

```
com/sun/jna/<arch-specific>/libjnidispatch.so
```

JNA will look for *your* native libraries under

```
<arch-specific>/<mapped-library-name>
```

You can set the system properties `-Djna.debug_load=true` and 
`-Djna.debug_load.jna=true` and JNA will emit to stdout where it's looking for your libraries and its own, respectively.

JNA provides the value for `<arch-specific>` in [Platform.RESOURCE_PREFIX](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/Platform.html#RESOURCE_PREFIX).

Comment: Great, but can you be more specific? I can't know if I supposed to look for a .so called libjnidispatch.so or am I supposed to perform a little steps to overcome this problem, only when trying "Android Tools" > "Add Native Support" it gives me a lot of project strange problems and errors like (make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/xmnetsdk] Error 5) and (
*** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop. line 199, external location: D:\NDK\android-ndk-r10d\build\core\add-application.mk)